# Some devices can't join room in Photon PUN. Can't seem to find out why?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I asked this question on Photon's forum, but I wanted to try it here as well.

I am really confused with this problem of mine.
I have a bingo game, where you can create a room, and others can join that room by entering the room name.

What is really weird, some people can join, some people are not able to join. And I can't seem to find out why.
I tested with 50 people, All devices located in India, most with different **Android** devices.

Now, some are able to join, some are not able.
It's not due to max players allowed, I checked that.
I thought maybe because of device limit, but there are like 30+ different device models there, so I believe it's not that.

The only thing that sounds logical to me is that this may be due to some Internet Provider limits, or some Internet Firewall limits? **Is this even possible**?

Please help this is driving me crazy. I'd share my code but I really don't think it's something with my code logic, because when I tested in Europe, I was able to connect to all the devices I tried to.

I really can't debug properly, because my client lives in India, and I live in Europe. As I said, when I tested here in Europe, I tested on many devices and all are working. Now my client is testing in India, and from 50 people only 2 can join the room.
We also tried to create from my device (in European region), and again only the same 2 people can join the room from India. So I guess it's not Cloud region related as well.

Once again, please help me, it's really hard for me to debug because this is happening overseas. I hope that it is a known issue/technicality, and someone will point me the way to enlightenment :)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Just to be clear, you've set the region to `EU` in `PhotonServerSettings` and gave that built to all the testers, while no one was able to join, correct?

Comment: No @Iggy the region is set to IN (india) in PhotonServerSettings. And the testers from India can't join, while I from EU can create and join..

Comment: Hm, I see, yeah looks like a difficult problem to debug, especially since it works on all of your devices. I'd recommend you log the state of the network, and let the person with the non-working device try it out, may as well be something wrong with reaching the server.

Comment: years later I have the same problem, did you find a solution?